# validation_frame argument in h2o PCA

Tags: pca, h2o

I am using the H2O machine learning suite for unsupervised modeling. I see that there is a validation_frame option. But I wonder if it is really used on the h2o pca algorithm.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, but it seems to be *not* a programming question. As such... off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not used.  There is no such thing as training and validation metrics in the PCA algorithm and the `validation_frame` argument should probably be deprecated.  You can verify this by looking at the validation metrics.

R example:

```
> library(h2o)
> h2o.init()
> fit <- h2o.prcomp(training_frame = as.h2o(iris), x = 1:5, validation_frame = as.h2o(iris), k = 3)
> fit@model$training_metrics
H2ODimReductionMetrics: pca

No model metrics available for PCA
> fit@model$validation_metrics
H2ODimReductionMetrics: pca

No model metrics available for PCA
```